# JavaScript getMonth

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to use JavaScript to display the date and time on my webapp.

Although I have had success doing this my date and time is printed as 29/5/13. I want it to have a zero in front of the month if it is less than ten. I have tried using an if statement but didnt have much sucess. My code that I currently have is:

```
<script language="javascript"> 

    today = new Date(); 
    document.write("<BR>Time: ", today.getHours(),":",today.getMinutes()); 
    document.write("<BR>Date: ", today.getDate(),"/",today.getMonth()+1,"/",today.getYear()-100);


</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "tried using an if statement but didnt have much success" - what exactly did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var today = new Date();
var month = ((today.getMonth() + 1) < 10) ? '0' + (today.getMonth() + 1) : (today.getMonth() + 1);
document.write("<BR>Time: ", today.getHours(), ":", today.getMinutes());
document.write("<BR>Date: ", today.getDate(), "/", month, "/", today.getYear() - 100);
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/m4Gj2/)

Comment: Why call `getMonth()` twice? Can be optimized very easily.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - While calling `getMonth()` multiple times isn't going to crash anyone's system, I'm sure the code could be refactored to save a few bytes. I was just addressing the OP's basic concerns.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this somehow wrong or not useful?

Comment: Not my downvote but it also does not deserve upvote. (Putting aside the fact it was already answered in the dupe :))

Comment: you wil have 9:5 for 5 past 9 here as well

Answer (score 4):

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Yy7Ft/)

```
function pad(num) {
  return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
```

To use:

```
+  pad(today.getMonth()+1))
```

Comment: Too awesome. [Works too](http://jsfiddle.net/uWBDR/1/)

Answer (score 1):

A different way of padding with zeros

```
function zfill(str, len) {
    var i = len - (''+str).length + 1;
    if (i > 0) return new Array(i).join('0') + str;
    return ''+str;
}
```

Then

```
zfill(5, 2); // "05"
```

Comment: Love this. The `new Array(i).join('0')` part is especially clever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
if (month.toString().length!==2) { month="0"+month; }
```